# Python: aggregating data by row count

Tags: python, aggregate

I'm trying to aggregate [this](http://ie.technion.ac.il/serveng/callcenterdata/index.html) call center data in various different ways in Python, for example mean q_time by type and priority. This is fairly straightforward using `df.groupby`.

However, I would also like to be able to aggregate by call volume. The problem is that each line of the data represents a call, so I'm not sure how to do it. If I'm just grouping by date then I can just use `'count'` as the aggregate function, but how would I aggregate by e.g. weekday, i.e. create a data frame like:

```
weekday    mean_row_count
   1           100
   2           150
   3           120
   4           220
   5           200
   6           30
   7           35
```

Is there a good way to do this? All I can think of is looping through each weekday and counting the number of unique dates, then dividing the counts per weekday by the number of unique dates, but I think this could get messy and maybe really slow it down if I need to also group by other variables, or do it by date and hour of the day.

Answer (score 0):

Since the date of each call is given, one idea is to implement a function to determine the day of the week from a given date. There are many ways to do this such as Conway's Doomsday algorithm.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_rule

One can then go through each line, determine the week day, and add to the count for each weekday.

Answer (score 0):

When I find myself thinking how to aggregate and query data in a versatile way, it think that the solution is probably a database. SQLite is a lightweight embedded database with high performances for simple use cases, and Python and a native support for it.

My advice here is : create a database and a table for your data, eventually add ancillary tables depending on your needs, load data into it, and use interative sqlite or Python scripts for your queries.